# How to exit a video from cv2.VideoCapture() once the video duration ends?

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I am trying to do a project using mediapipe for pose detection. I want the input data to be mp4 files --> "video_path". Currently the video just keeps going on loop - How do I get the video to close once it finishes? For eg. my input video is currently 15s - so I want it to exit once it hits 15s.

```
#Video Feed

# Setting up video capture device
# 0 = built-in webcam & 2 = External webcam
# If want to grab a video clip, type the name of video and its file loc within (...)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Start the holistic model
# 'Holistic' allows me to access the Holistic estimation model
# '0.6' = 60%

with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()

         #recoloring it back to BGR b/c it will rerender back to opencv
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False

        results = holistic.process(image)

        #setting image writeable back to true to be able process it
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        #Draw the pose landmarks
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2))

        try:

            pose = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            pose_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in pose]).flatten())

            row = pose_row
            row.insert(0, class_name)

            # data is appended to csv. if csv does not exist, new file is created
            with open('Pose_keypoints.csv', mode='a', newline='') as f:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                csv_writer.writerow(row)

        except:
            pass

        cv2.imshow('Training Data Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried "ret=True" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `if not ret:` condition works

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
```

I have also confirmed if it works with your script

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np
import csv

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic

with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

         #recoloring it back to BGR b/c it will rerender back to opencv
        image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image.flags.writeable = False

        results = holistic.process(image)

        #setting image writeable back to true to be able process it
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        #Draw the pose landmarks
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,117,66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245,66,230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2))

        try:

            pose = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
            pose_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in pose]).flatten())

            row = pose_row
            row.insert(0, "Landmarks")

            # data is appended to csv. if csv does not exist, new file is created
            with open('Pose_keypoints.csv', mode='a', newline='') as f:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                csv_writer.writerow(row)

        except:
            pass

        cv2.imshow('Training Data Feed', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```